# NSJSONSerialization parsing not returning all values in response Array/ Dictionary

Tags: ios5, nsurlconnection, nsjsonserialization

I am using native `NSURLConnectionDelegate` with `NSJsonSerialization`. I am getting the REST response but not all the values it contains.

I have this JSON response in web-browser :

```
{
"error" : {
    "err_num" : 0,
    "err_message" : ""
}, 
"company" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "company_string1"
},
"company" : {
    "id" : 7,
    "name" : "company_string2"
},
"company" : {
    "id" : 19,
    "name" : "company_string3"
},
"company" : {
    "id" : 13,
    "name" : "company_string4"
},
"company" : {
    "id" : 14,
    "name" : "company_string5"
}
}
```

I am using `NSURLConnection` asynchronously and implement

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}   // receivedData is NSMutuableData initialized before
```

and in `connectionDidFinishLoading` I do:

```
NSMutableDictionary *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

When I log, I get

```
{
    "err_message" = "";
   "err_num" = 0;
}
{
    id = 14;
    name = "company_string5";
}
```

If I use `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` I get

```
{
    "err_message" = "";
    "err_num" = 0;
} 
{
    id = 1;
    name = company_string1;
}
```

Also checked `NSDictionary`, but I get same result. Is their some problem with the JSON here due to duplicate keys, is it only returning the last/first one? I also happened to check online, almost all says its a valid JSON. It is not giving any error!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the JSON is not an array (unless you left out some characters). You're presumably enumerating through the "array" and hence getting the dictionary values, without keys. NSLog the value of "array" itself and you will see all your keys there (in what is actually an NSDictionary).

(And if the keys really are all "company", you will only receive one "company" element.  Multiple identical keys would be invalid JSON sent from the other end.)

Comment: This is exactly same Json response that I get in the browser, I presumed it initially it be a invalid JSON, but now i think I was correct. It should be a nested JSON with only one key for "company" .

Comment: @Vacca What should be nested JSON?  If there are multiple identical keys within a dictionary (JSON "object") then that is invalid JSON.